# Decrease in index URLs,and drop in traffic

Tags: google-analytics, search-engine-indexing, traffic

A site that I work for has had a drop in traffic over the last few weeks.and also Decrease in INDEXING the no of URL's .

However, having had a look in Google Webmaster tools, there has been a big drop in the number or URLs indexed and drop in Traffic also.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately there is far too little information for us to know why this might have occurred, or for this question to be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: You have a few issues with this site. The immediate pop-up can be a problem. But also your SEO is not good. I also noticed that from a users standpoint that I could never reach the end of the page to click a link. The fact that new content is added as I scrolled could be an issue. This is a nice looking site, but from a UX/SEO perspective, there are things to look at. You also have 30k pages indexed. How many are you expecting? Get back to basics. Pay attention to the massively top-heavy code and do your SEO home work. Also do not get cute with JavaScript. JS can be a site killer.

Comment: Sorry @dan. I was a bit quick on the draw. There are too many issues with this site to sum up in an answer anyway. I was looking for an obvious set of simple things that could be done. But I found too many things to give a fast answer.

Comment: Thanks For your reply.Can you please tell me what should i do in SEO.in which section improvement is required ie ON PAGE SEO,OFF Page SEO, Link Building, Navigation of website, UX of Website and Others

Comment: That is far too large for these comments or even for an answer. But I can tell to add an h1 tag (generally), remove the keywords tag, remove the inline JS, and add content. When I look at the source code for the home page, there really is no content for the page. It is impossible to rank this page. I did look at one of your posts. The content starts 2/3rds of the way down the page. You are using a CMS that is making your pages far too top heavy. I would say clean up the code for starters. Push your content to the top and make sure that you are doing traditional stuff along the way.

Comment: @closetnoc No problem. If the OP can edit the question with specific details, such as _when_ this occurred, after _what changes_ were made, etc...then it might prove helpful to others in the future and be reopened. General SEO and site reviews/advice is off-topic here though because it won't be searchable under our Q/A format or helpful to others.

Comment: @dan Not to say this guys site has a lot of issues, but what I saw was too big to really get into. The site is actually fairly good. It just needs someone to go through it and get back to basics on some of this.

Comment: @closetnoc Unfortunately this isn't the right site for extensive feedback like that :-/ I'm marking this as a duplicate question instead so the OP can at least review the basics contained in that.